# Docusign Chat Location?

Tags: docusignapi

I've seen other projects have a [Slack](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/02/come-join-firebase-slack-community_13.html), [Gitter](https://gitter.im/reactjs/redux), [IRC](https://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/support/irc/), or [Discord](http://www.reactiflux.com/) chat room where discussion and announcements happen.  Its good for questions like "Did the API go down for you?" that don't make sense to ask on Stack Overflow.

Does Docusign have something like this?  I think Discord or Gitter are probably the best options for creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [DocuSign Trust center](https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/system-status/) for any platform issues.

We have a [customer forum system](https://support.docusign.com/en/community) that you can also use. It is not monitored by the Developer Center Staff the way StackOverflow is.

DocuSign has zero scheduled maintenance time and our uptime has been over 99.99% for a couple of years now. (And we're still sweating that last .01%.)